# msal-node using old jsonwebtoken npm pkg triggering npm audit issue

Tags: npm, jwt, azure-ad-msal, tedious, azure-identity

we are using mssql npm package
it has dependency with like below:

`mssql > tedious > @azure/identity > @azure/msal-node > jsonwebtoken`

Now we are getting below audit error:
https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-27h2-hvpr-p74q
[image: npm-audit-error]

Any one already having this issue and know any workaround?

Comment: I have reported this as [an issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/5526).  Probably people have also reported it as a vulnerability to their security people, but naturally there is no visibility of that, and I suspect that the maintainers could deal with this easily.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary measure, I had to use yarn's *Selective dependency resolutions* https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/

in package.json:

```
"resolutions": {
    "@azure/msal-node": "^1.17.0"
  }
```